# What switching methods do SOHO switches use, like in cisco switches used?

Tags: switch, switching, network

Switching methods like,

- Store and Forward
- Cut-Through
- Fragment-free

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Consumer-grade hardware is explicitly off-topic here, but since this is a more general question: all low and practically all medium-grade switches use *store-and-forward* switching.

High-performance, low-latency switches often use *fragment-free* with fallback to store-and-forward on a port where the error rate exceeds a certain threshold. Note that current fragment-free switches support 802.1Q/ad VLAN tagging and can only start forwarding *after* having received the VLAN tag(s).

Pure *cut-through* is more or less obsolete.